# brew doctor Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite, brew-doctor

I'm sort of new to programming and in the path of setting the environment ready under Mac OS X Yosemite I ran into some issues under the `brew doctor` command.

It says

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew
maintainers with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use
Homebrew for is working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them.
Thanks!
```

but I don't really know what to expect and to avoid future issues I'd like to see the output "Your system is ready to brew"

First I ran the `brew purge` command with the following output

```
horus:~ rsmendes$ brew prune 
Pruned 0 dead formulae Pruned 136
symbolic links and 4 directories from /usr/local
```

Now I'm getting dylibs warning. I've read that this is solved by removing this files, but also read that it is possible to break something, and I'm uncertain of how to proceed.

I'm also getting header, unbrewed .la, unbrewed .pc and unbrewed static libraries that all seem to be related to the dylibs mentioned.

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't
put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building
Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libfuse4x.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.80.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs.9.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libublio.1.dylib
```

Comment: There is more than one way to install things to /usr/local and brew is basically just telling you that you've installed packages via some other mechanism. It doesn't usually cause problems, unless you try to install the same package via homebrew. Your choices are basically either 1) remove everything homebrew complains about, which may result in missing dependencies (make backups first); or 2) ignore those warnings.